# Lentitud CharIndex + string muy largo

Tags: sql

**Modifico la pregunta**

La cuestion era, tengo un SQL que tarda mas de 60s en devolver una respuesta. Algo impensable para un buscador!

He encotrado la razon:

*CharIndex*

¿Porque va lento?

Tengo unos 300 resultados a mostrar (en una subquery) que luego paso por un select que filtro con un charindex. El problema reside en que recoge una string con casi una treintena de valores separados por comas... y tiene que comparar esos 300 resultados con cada uno de los valores para verificar que cumple la condición!!

Total, ¿Existe alguna manera de simplificar o acelerar esa condicion? He pensado tratarlo con bucles o tablas temporales, pero creo que tardara mas todavia...

Aqui el condicionante:

```
SET @holons = 'CC01,CC02,CC03,CC04,CC05,CC06,CE01,CE02,CL01,CL02,CL03,CL04,CN01,CN02,CN03,CN04,CN05,CN06,CN07,CO01,CP01,CP02,CP03,CP04,CS01,CS02,CS03,CS04'
```

Aqui la condicion:

```
CHARINDEX(',' + FULL_SEARCH.Holon + ',', ',' + @HOLONS + ',') > 0
```

**TIEMPO DE EJECUCION**

> 00:01:01

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
    FULL_SEARCH.* 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Contactos.IdContacto,
        Clientes.NombreCliente, 
        Clientes.CodigoCliente,
        Clientes.Holon, 
        Contactos.NombreContacto,
        Departamentos.Titulo AS Departamento,
        Cargos.Titulo AS Cargo,
        Contactos.Telefono,
        Contactos.Email,
        Contactos.Movil,
        Clientes.CodigoPostal,
        Clientes.Poblacion,
        Clientes.CodigoPostalPoblacion,
        Relevancias.Titulo AS Relevancia,
        Clientes.Proyecto,
        GruposClientes.IdGrupo,
        Clientes.Responsable,
        Clientes.Direccion,
        Contactos.Descripcion,
        Contactos.Observaciones,
        Clientes.Segmento,
        Clientes.Subsegmento
    FROM 
        Contactos
        INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.CodigoCliente = Contactos.CodigoCliente
        INNER JOIN Departamentos ON Departamentos.IdDepartamento = Contactos.IdDepartamento
        LEFT JOIN Cargos ON Cargos.IdCargo = Contactos.IdCargo
        LEFT JOIN Relevancias ON Relevancias.IdRelevancia = Contactos.IdRelevancia
        LEFT JOIN GruposClientes ON GruposClientes.CodigoCliente = Contactos.CodigoCliente
        LEFT JOIN ContactosAcciones ON ContactosAcciones.IdContacto = Contactos.IdContacto
    WHERE 
        contactos.Activo = 1
        AND  (@CodigoCliente IS NULL OR @CodigoCliente = '' OR Clientes.CodigoCliente like '%' + @CodigoCliente + '%') 
        AND  (@NombreCliente IS NULL OR @NombreCliente = '' OR Clientes.NombreCliente like '%' + @NombreCliente + '%')    
        AND  (@NombreContacto IS NULL OR @NombreContacto = '' OR Contactos.NombreContacto like '%' + @NombreContacto + '%')
        AND  (@Departamento IS NULL OR @Departamento = '' OR Departamentos.Titulo like '%' + @Departamento + '%')
        AND  (@IdGrupo IS NULL OR @IdGrupo = '' OR GruposClientes.IdGrupo = @IdGrupo)
        AND  (@Responsable IS NULL OR @Responsable = '' OR Clientes.Responsable like '%' + @Responsable + '%')
        AND  (@AccionesMarketing IS NULL OR @AccionesMarketing = '' OR ContactosAcciones.IdAccionMarketingContacto like '%' + @AccionesMarketing + '%') 
        AND  (@Proyecto IS NULL OR @Proyecto = '' OR Clientes.Proyecto like '%' + @Proyecto + '%') 
    ) FULL_SEARCH       
WHERE CHARINDEX(FULL_SEARCH.Holon,@HOLONS) > 0
```

**PARAMETROS**

```
@CodigoCliente = NULL,
@NombreCliente = NULL,
@NombreContacto = NULL,
@Departamento = NULL,
@Holons = N'''CC01,CC02,CC03,CC04,CC05,CC06,CE01,CE02,CL01,CL02,CL03,CL04,CN01,CN02,CN03,CN04,CN05,CN06,CN07,CO01,CP01,CP02,CP03,CP04,CS01,CS02,CS03,CS04''',
@GruposClientes = NULL,
@Holon = NULL,
@IdGrupo = 5,
@Responsable = NULL,
@AccionesMarketing = NULL,
@Proyecto = NULL
```

**RESULTADOS**

```
    IdContacto  Holon
1   36901   CN04
2   36902   CN04
3   36903   CN04
4   36904   CN04
5   36905   CN04
6   36906   CN04
7   36907   CN04
8   36908   CN04
9   36909   CN04
10  36910   CN04
11  36911   CN04
12  36912   CN04
13  36921   CN02
14  36922   CN02
15  36923   CN02
16  36924   CN02
17  36925   CN02
18  36926   CN02
19  36927   CN02
20  36928   CN02
21  36929   CN02
22  36930   CN02
23  36931   CN02
24  36932   CN02
25  36933   CN02
26  36934   CN02
27  36935   CN02
28  36936   CN02
29  36937   CN02
30  36938   CN02
31  36939   CN02
32  36940   CN02
33  36941   CN02
34  36942   CN02
35  36943   CN02
36  42743   CN06
37  43154   CN06
38  45341   CN01
39  45342   CN01
40  45343   CN01
41  45344   CN01
42  45345   CN01
43  45346   CN01
44  45347   CN01
45  45348   CN01
46  45349   CN01
47  45350   CN01
48  45770   CN06
49  45771   CN06
50  45772   CN06
51  45773   CN06
52  45774   CN06
53  45775   CN06
54  45776   CN06
55  45777   CN06
56  45778   CN06
57  45779   CN06
58  45780   CN06
59  45781   CN06
60  45782   CN06
61  45783   CN06
62  45784   CN06
63  45785   CN06
64  46694   CN06
65  46695   CN06
66  46696   CN06
67  46697   CN06
68  46698   CN06
69  46699   CN06
70  46700   CN06
71  46701   CN06
72  46702   CN06
73  46703   CN06
74  46704   CN06
75  46705   CN06
76  46706   CN06
77  46715   CN05
78  46716   CN05
79  46717   CN05
80  46718   CN05
81  46719   CN06
82  46720   CN06
83  48928   CN06
84  48929   CN06
85  48930   CN06
86  48931   CN06
87  48932   CN06
88  48934   CN06
89  48935   CN06
90  48936   CN06
91  48937   CN06
92  48938   CN06
93  48972   CN05
94  48973   CN05
95  60565   CC02
96  60566   CC02
97  60567   CC02
98  60568   CC02
99  60569   CC02
100 60570   CC02
101 60571   CC02
102 60572   CC02
103 60573   CC02
104 60574   CC02
105 60575   CC02
106 60576   CC02
107 60577   CC02
108 60578   CC02
109 60579   CC02
110 60580   CC02
111 60581   CC02
112 60582   CC02
113 60583   CC02
114 60584   CC02
115 60585   CC02
116 60586   CC02
117 60587   CC02
118 60588   CC02
119 60589   CC02
120 60590   CC02
121 60591   CC02
122 60592   CC02
123 60593   CC02
124 60594   CC02
125 60595   CC02
126 60596   CC02
127 60597   CC02
128 60598   CC02
129 60599   CC02
130 60600   CC02
131 60601   CC02
132 60613   CC01
133 60614   CC01
134 60615   CC01
135 60616   CC01
136 60617   CC01
137 60619   CC01
138 60620   CC01
139 60621   CC01
140 60622   CC01
141 60623   CC01
142 60625   CC01
143 60626   CC01
144 60627   CC01
145 60628   CC01
146 60629   CC01
147 60630   CC01
148 60631   CC01
149 60632   CC01
150 61801   CC01
151 61802   CC01
152 61803   CC01
153 61806   CC02
154 61807   CC02
155 61808   CC02
156 61809   CC02
157 61810   CC02
158 61811   CC02
159 61812   CC02
160 66392   CC04
161 66393   CC04
162 66394   CC04
163 66395   CC04
164 66396   CC04
165 66397   CC04
166 66398   CC04
167 66399   CC04
168 70920   CC02
169 70921   CC02
170 70922   CC02
171 70923   CC02
172 70924   CC02
173 77011   CL04
174 77013   CL04
175 77014   CL04
176 77015   CL04
177 77018   CL04
178 77019   CL04
179 87543   CS03
180 87544   CS03
181 87545   CS03
182 87546   CS03
183 87547   CS03
184 87548   CS03
185 87549   CS03
186 87550   CS03
187 87551   CS02
188 87552   CS02
189 87553   CS02
190 87555   CS02
191 87556   CS02
192 87557   CS02
193 87558   CS02
194 87559   CS02
195 87560   CS02
196 87561   CS02
197 87562   CS02
198 87563   CS02
199 87564   CS02
200 87565   CS02
201 87566   CS02
202 87567   CS02
203 87568   CS02
204 87569   CS02
205 87570   CS02
206 87571   CS02
207 87572   CS02
208 87573   CS02
209 87574   CS02
210 87575   CS02
211 87576   CS02
212 87577   CS02
213 87578   CS02
214 87579   CS02
215 87580   CS02
216 87581   CS04
217 87582   CS04
218 87583   CS04
219 87584   CS04
220 87585   CS04
221 87586   CS04
222 87587   CS04
223 87588   CS04
224 87589   CS04
225 87590   CS04
226 87591   CS04
227 87592   CS04
228 87593   CS04
229 87594   CS04
230 96352   CN05
231 96543   CN02
232 96544   CN02
233 100390  CP04
234 100391  CP04
235 100392  CP04
236 100393  CP04
237 100394  CP04
238 100395  CP04
239 100396  CP04
240 100397  CP04
241 100398  CP04
242 100399  CP04
243 100400  CP04
244 100401  CP04
245 100402  CP04
246 100403  CP04
247 100404  CP04
248 100405  CP01
249 100406  CP01
250 100407  CP01
251 100408  CP01
252 100409  CP01
253 100410  CP01
254 100411  CP01
255 100412  CP01
256 100413  CP01
257 100414  CP01
258 100415  CP01
259 100416  CP01
260 100417  CP01
261 100418  CP01
262 100419  CP01
263 100420  CP02
264 100421  CP02
265 100422  CP02
266 100423  CP02
267 100424  CP02
268 100425  CP02
269 100426  CP02
270 100427  CP02
271 100428  CP02
272 100429  CP02
273 100430  CP02
274 100431  CP02
275 106692  CN02
276 106693  CN02
277 106918  CN04
278 106919  CN04
279 108058  CC03
280 108140  CS03
281 108435  CP01
282 108682  CC03
283 108883  CC03
284 109801  CC03
285 110669  CN06
286 111200  CN06
287 111222  CN06
288 111352  CC02
289 111443  CN02
```

*Obviamente he retirado datos sensibles de los resultados*

Comment: Una pregunta, cual es el motivo de añadir  ',' (coma) al inicio y final de cada parámetro?

Comment: @JaimitoPaco la verdad es que no lo se, es un proyecto recogido. Y estoy trabajando en disminuir el tiempo de carga de todo. Me falta esto que me esta dando mucha guerra.

Comment: Si la consulta interna como bien decías solo tarda 2 segundos, el charindex se ejecuta sobre la tabla ya formada en 2 segundos, dices que esa consulta interna te recoge 300 resultados, no deberia ser demasiado para el charindex, intenta quitando las comas que agregas a los parámetros a ver si afecta de alguna manera ir agregando caracteres 300 veces, a ver si aprecias diferencias

Comment: @JaimitoPaco ya he colocado quitado las comas, pero lo pensado... nada XD He puesto mas datos (query, resultados,...)

Comment: intenta en el join de Clientes `INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.CodigoCliente = Contactos.CodigoCliente and CHARINDEX(Clientes.Holon,@HOLONS) > 0` eliminando tambien el charindex y el where final

Comment: nada @JaimitoPaco...

Comment: Me resulta raro que el `CHARINDEX` sea el culpable, sobre todo por que es una función bástante simple y solo se invoca una vez por fila. Me suena más a un problema derivado de la subconsulta que haces. Yo probaría primero que nada quitar la subconsulta y resolverlo todo en la consulta real. Saludos.